# Find the area of ​the trapezoidal surface $ABCD$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area, plane-geometry

For reference:

> In the figure shown, calculate the area of ​​the trapezoidal surface $ABCD$, if $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{CD} = 150^o$and $BM=MA$. (Answer:$R^2$)

[image]

Let $R = 1, AM=BM = x:$

$\sin(15°)=\frac{MC}{2}\implies MC=\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$

$\tan(15°)=\frac{BC}{2x}\implies BC=2x(2-\sqrt3)$

$\triangle BMC: x^2=\frac{10+3\sqrt 3}{73}$

$S=\frac{(BC+AD)×AB}{2}=x^2(4-2\sqrt3)+x\sqrt{4-x^2}$

$\implies=\frac{22-8\sqrt 3}{73}+\frac{51+8\sqrt 3}{73}=1=R^2$

Is there another way of solving? Without considering $R = 1$?

[image]

Comment: @MathLover  but AM is diferente CM...

Comment: @MathLover $\angle CAD$ inscribed therefore $\frac{150}{2}=75 \therefore \angle BAC =15^o$

Comment: Understood. I was thinking of your construction incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution that avoids much calculation -

$ \small [BCDM] = [BCD] + [BDM] = [BCA] + [ADM]$
$ \small  = 2 [BCM] + [ADM]$

But also, $ \small [BCDM] = [BCM] + [CDM] \implies [ADM] + [BCM] = [CDM]$

$ \small \implies [BCDA] = [ADM] + [BCM] + [CDM] = 2 [CDM]$

Drop a perp from $ \small C$ to $ \small DM$, which is $ \small R/2$.

$ \small \displaystyle [CDM] = \frac 12 \cdot \frac R 2 \cdot 2R = \frac{R^2}{2}$

$ \therefore \small [BCDA] = R^2$